Как отключить объект Player(либо заморозить Rigidbody) по нажатию кнопки внутри триггера
Я создаю свой жд симулятор. В нём я хочу организовать мультиплеер. Но до сих пор я не могу сделать возможность лично для любого игрока сесть на стул в локомотиве. Проблемма в том что в мультиплеере их несколько и как отключать лишь того, который находится в триггере сидения я понять не могу. Я уже пытался использовать такие методы как SetActive, Rigidbody.constraints и Destroy, но в силу моих малых знаний добиться рабочего варианта у меня так и не получилось.
Вот скрипт:
public class CamControllerMultipleer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CamMashinista;
    public GameObject VnehCam;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
        {
            CamMashinista.SetActive(true);
            VnehCam.SetActive(false);
            
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
        {
            CamMashinista.SetActive(false);
            VnehCam.SetActive(false);
            
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("t"))
        {
            CamMashinista.SetActive(false);
            VnehCam.SetActive(true);
            
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
            {
                //Здесь и нужно как-то отключать gameObject с тэгом Player
            }
        }
    }  
}

В нём:
CamMashinista - Это камера прикреплённая к кабине
VnehCam - Это камера внешнего обзора
Забыл уточнить: создание идёт в 3д, а не в 2д. Так же пытался искать в интернете как можно отключить только тот GameObject, который находится именно в этом триггере, но ничего найти не смог. Буду бесконечно благодарен если вы не только сможете понят что я прошу, но и помочь. Заранее спасибо!
Я ожидал отключения лично того объекта, что находится в триггере

other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>() и делайте со скриптом что хотите.

Но ведь так я получаю комонент персонажа, а мне нужно выключить его как объект(что то на подобии SetActive(true/false)). Хотя возможно вы и правы. Но что-то подобное я уже делал до того как написать этот вопрос и в итоге камера переключалась, но персонаж был виден и передвигался, а выходя из триггера и вовсе всё не работало. В любом случае спасибо что ответили я обязательно проверю

Если вам не сложно, можете написать вторую строчку с помощью которой и будет отключаться игрок(как объект или просто обездвиживаться). На сколько я понял после вашей строки мне нужно отключить скрипт передвижения плеера или что-то в этом духе?

без понятия, всё зависит от вашей логике. Вызовите SetActive(false) например для него, но учтите что на неактивных объектах скрипты не работают.

Я написал other.gameObject.GetComponent(); а после  other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
но он выдаёт мне ошибку в которой жалуется на несуществование имени Player

Я ж не знаю, как там ваш скрирт игрока назвывается. Вообще не помню, но можете попробовать other.gameObject.SetActive(...) напрямую.

Ох, забыл. На игроке висят: FirstPersonMovement; Jump; Crouch(присед) а остальные скрипты фонарика, видимости для других игроков и тд. Наверное нужно отключать скрипт FirstPersonMovement или как? И ещё метод напрямую выключать other.gameObject я уже ранее пробовал он не работает, а плеер так же уходит

Это уже вопрос проектирования, а не доступа к объекту как в изначальном вопросе. Здесь пряд-ли кто-то поможет.

Что-ж тогда я просто могу получить скрипт игрока и отключить его, так?

Не попробуете - не узнаете.
